# MKNetworkKit how to get server response header with session cookie

Tags: ios, objective-c, mknetworkkit

I am using **MKNetworkKit** library.

My server seems to let my authenticate using HTTP Post, I get back some JSON data from my server:

```
{auth: true}
```

However, I want to store the server generated session cookie but I don't know how to use 
**MKNetworkKit to get the session cookie**

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4):

-_-!

Finally, after all that digging around, get the response header like this:

```
-(void)login
{
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [params setObject:@"testusername" forKey:@"username"];
    [params setObject:@"abcdef123" forKey:@"password"];

    MKNetworkOperation *op = [self.mkEngine operationWithPath:@"/auth/local.json" params:params httpMethod:@"POST"];

    [op addCompletionHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation)
    {
        NSLog(@"response headers: %@", completedOperation.readonlyResponse.allHeaderFields);
    } errorHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Server error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];

    [self.mkEngine enqueueOperation:op];
}
```